# Azure webapps and functionapps deployment fails randomly

Tags: azure, jenkins-pipeline, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

The deployments to azure webapps and functionapps fail randomly during the deployment in pipeline. Sometimes the deployments are done successfully without any error but fail at random builds. Trying to deploy multiple webapps and functionapps in parallel. Using Jenkins pipeline for deployment.

The command which I am using for deploying webapps is `az webapp deployment source config-zip -g xxx -n xxx --src xxx`

Log when failed:

```
09:47:31  Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
09:47:31  Configuring default logging for the app, if not already enabled
09:47:31  Zip deployment failed. {'id': 'XXXX', 'status': 3, 'status_text': '', 'author_email': 'N/A', 'author': 'N/A', 'deployer': 'ZipDeploy', 'message': 'Created via a push deployment', 'progress': '', 'received_time': '2021-01-20T08:47:00.3856858Z', 'start_time': '2021-01-20T08:47:00.791329Z', 'end_time': '2021-01-20T08:47:18.7995378Z', 'last_success_end_time': None, 'complete': True, 'active': False, 'is_temp': False, 'is_readonly': True, 'url': 'https://xxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest', 'log_url': 'https://xxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log', 'site_name': 'xxxxx', 'provisioningState': None}. Please run the command az webapp log deployment show -n xxxx -g xxxx
```

deployment log url from azure shows:

````
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"No log found for 'latest'.","ExceptionType":"System.IO.FileNotFoundException","StackTrace":"   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.DeploymentManager.GetLogEntries(String id) in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Deployment\\DeploymentManager.cs:line 93\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Deployment.DeploymentController.GetLogEntry(String id) in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services\\Deployment\\DeploymentController.cs:line 375"}```
````

Comment: parallel steps in the same job use the same Jenkins workspace until you specified to run on the different agent, so make sure you are not cleaning or overriding the deployable time to time

Comment: @SamitKumarPatel Thanks for the suggestion , but I already use different agents and different jobs.